# How to get city name using geolocation and redirect to an URL for that city?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

For example, if the user visits http://example.com and I get "New York" as the city based on geolocation, then redirect the user to http://example.com/NY

If it's "Los Angeles" redirect to http://example.com/LA and if it was any other city, the user would be directed to a 3rd URL.

How can I do this?

Here's my current attempt/code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GEOIP DB - jQuery example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Country: <span id="country"></span>
    <div>State: <span id="state"></span>
    <div>City: <span id="city"></span>
    <div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span>
    <div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>
    <div>IP: <span id="ip"></span>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: "callback",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function( location ) {
                $('#country').html(location.country_name);
                $('#state').html(location.state);
                $('#city').html(location.city);
                $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
                $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
                $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);  
                $routes = {"Los Angeles": "http://google.com/LA", "New York": "http://google.com/NY"}
if ( routes[location.city] ) { window.location.href = routes[location.city] }
            }

        }); 

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According what I see in your code, you must add the city that you want to the routes object, like this:

```
{
 "Los Angeles": "http://google.com/LA", 
 "New York": "http://google.com/NY", 
 "Other City": "http://google.com/othercity"
}
```